# google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.errors.InvalidAppConfigError

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk, google-app-engine-php

Getting below error after runnnig command "dev_appserver.py C:\Newfolder"

google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.errors.InvalidAppConfigError: In env: flex, only the following runtimes are allowed: ('python-compat', 'java', 'java7', 'go', 'custom')

I have installed php version 8.0.6 , and i'm trying to run a sample php application on localhost using google app engine's sdk.

my app.yaml looks like this:
runtime: php8
env: flex

runtime_config:
document_root: Newfolder

I tried putting runtime as custom , php72, php55 and even php80(since my php version is 8.0.6)
but still am getting the same error

referring this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/using-local-server

Comment: The page you link to says you need to use PHP5.  You are using old GAE stuff so recent PHP is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use php in flex environment your app.yaml needs to look something similar to this:

```yaml
 
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: web

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

The php version that app engine flex will use is the default `PHP 7.3`, but if you want to use another version you can specify it in the `composer.json` as this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#choosing_a_php_version) says